# Xamarin shared code project created in Visual Studio for Mac fails to load in Windows

Tags: windows, xamarin, f#, visual-studio-2017

I created a Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio for Mac as a shared project.  When I cloned my repository in Windows and tried to open it in Visual Studio 2017, I was greeted by this error:

[image]

I searched all of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio` for the `Microsoft.CodeSharing.FSharp.targets` file and didn't find it anywhere there.

I have Xamarin installed:

[image]

as well as Visual F#:

[image]

Is there some other thing I need to have installed?  Should I write a `Choose`/`When` item in my msbuild file?